# Transform df into edges df for collaboration network

Tags: r

I have this df, which contains information on collaboration of articles:

```
     author    author2 author3 author4
1      A       D       E       F
2      B       G
3      C       H       F
```

I need to create an `edges` dataframe, which contains the relationship between the authors, like this:

```
    from      to 
1      A       D   
2      A       E
3      A       F  
4      B       G
5      C       H
6      C       F
7      D       E
8      D       F
9      E       F
11     H       F
```

any ideas how to do it?

Comment: I would check `igraph` package.  Sorry, have to go now

Answer (score 1):

We can `gather` each column against the remaining columns i.e. to the left of that column and then binds all.

```
library(tidyverse)
map_dfr(names(df)[-length(df)], ~select(df,.x:ncol(df)) %>% gather( k,to,-.x) %>% 
                                 arrange(!!ensym(.x)) %>% select(-k) %>% filter(to!='') %>% 
                                 rename(form=starts_with('author')))

    form to
1     A  D
2     A  E
3     A  F
4     B  G
5     C  H
6     C  F
7     D  E
8     D  F
9     H  F
10    E  F
```

## Data

```
df <- structure(list(author = c("A", "B", "C"), author2 = c("D", "G", 
"H"), author3 = c("E", "", "F"), author4 = c("F","", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```

Comment: hey there! I've tried using your code, but got this error: Error in .x:ncol(df) : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: It works fine for me. I'm using tidyverse 1.2.1, dplyr0.7.6

Comment: i've started a new session, used your df and still got the same error message =/

Comment: what's that .x:ncol(df) argument? is there another way to do it?

Comment: In each iteration, we select certain columns i.e. in the first iteration we select the colmns form "author" to  the end of df, in the 2nd we select from author2 to the end as so on. Try `which(.x == names(df)):ncol(df)`

Answer (score 1):

You could apply `combn` row-wise inside a function, no need for packages.

```
edges <- setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(d)), function(x) 
  matrix(unlist(t(combn(na.omit(unlist(d[x, ])), 2))), ncol=2)))), c("from", "to"))
edges
#    from to
# 1     A  D
# 2     A  E
# 3     A  F
# 4     D  E
# 5     D  F
# 6     E  F
# 7     B  G
# 8     C  H
# 9     C  F
# 10    H  F
```

Or, using `igraph` package as *@akrun* suggested.

```
library(igraph)
edges <- do.call(rbind, apply(d, 1, function(x) 
  as_data_frame(graph_from_data_frame(t(combn(na.omit(x), 2))))))
edges
#    from to
# 1     A  D
# 2     A  E
# 3     A  F
# 4     D  E
# 5     D  F
# 6     E  F
# 7     B  G
# 8     C  H
# 9     C  F
# 10    H  F
```

***Data***

```
d <- structure(list(author = c("A", "B", "C"), author2 = c("D", "G", 
"H"), author3 = c("E", NA, "F"), author4 = c("F", NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```